# UIModalViewController Hidden behind a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am working with a sliding menu, like you would see in the Facebook or Path app.

In the rear menu I am wanting to allow the user to add an image by using the camera or photo library.

The issue I am having is the main view controller, the one that I slide, is always on top.

The Action Sheet presents just fine, but the modal view controller is hidden partially by the main view controller.

Here's my picker code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _UIPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _UIPicker.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)profilePicButtonTapped
{  
    UIActionSheet * actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set Up Your Profile Picture" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Photo Library", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [actionSheet showInView:_rearTableView];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        _UIPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:_UIPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        _UIPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:_UIPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage * selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    _profileImageView.image = selectedImage;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to solve it would be to hide the main ViewController when you present the picker and show it again once it's dismissed. Assuming you have a reference to the main ViewController, just set it's `view.hidden` property to YES.

Another way to handle it would be to present it from the main ViewController instead of the rear menu.

Comment: Makes sense, yet my main ViewController will not hide when I set the property to YES. Best example to see what I am wanting to accomplish is the GroupMe app and how you set a Groups profile image.